# Left Outer Join in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, caml-query, joined-view

I have 2 lists in SharePoint 2010. First List E lists all locations.

In the second list H I use first E list as lookup for Location. Every month users inputs information in list H.

List E has (Location)

List H has(Locations (lookup from list E), Month, Inventory, Name)

I need to know which location DID NOT provided inventory this month.

I used .net before and in SQL the statement I used was

```
SELECT    E.Canteen_Location
FROM    dbo.v_Location AS E LEFT OUTER JOIN
               dbo.tblInventory AS H ON H.Canteen = E.CanteenNum  And Month=@Month
WHERE (H.Canteen IS NULL)
```

Now we moved to SharePoint 2010 and I do not know if this is even possible. Can somebody help me with this?

Larisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, in your `Joins` node add a Join with `type="LEFT"`, something like this:

```
  <Join Type="LEFT" ListAlias="h">
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Canteen" RefType="Id" />
      <FieldRef List="v_location" Name="CanteenNum" />
    </Eq>
  </Join>
```

[Here is a good example](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-list-joins-spquery-enchancements)

You also may want to look into using [LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with [SPMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538255%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as this will provide an easier syntax for querying SharePoint.

Syntax with LINQ would look like this:

```
var query = from e in db.v_location
            join h in db.tblInventory
               on h.Canteen equals e.CanteenNum into sh
            from x in sh.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where h.Canteen == null
            select new {
               e.Canteen_Location
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Larisa,

CAML Query do allow LEFT joins using `<Join>` tag... See [Joins and Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article on MSDN...

In Join there is a `Type` attribute whose value can either be `INNER` or `LEFT`, see [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535061%28v=office.14%29.aspx)...

If you can't figure out, I can give your complete CAML Query... Let me know!

Comment: Arsalan! I would appreciate complete CAML query. thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess Ryan has already given the answer!